# How to determine the correct size for terms aggregation, which will produce accurate aggregation results?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, resthighlevelclient

As I read through document for Terms Aggregation, I came across the fact that the results from Term Aggregation are not always accurate, but we can increase the size to get the accurate results.

I know : -

1. How Query-Then-Fetch works.
2. How top terms are calculated at each shard(shard_size) and then
   merge at co-ordinator node(size).
3. What "doc_count_error_upper_bound" means, and how it can help in
   determining that there may be error in top results and we need to
   increase the size.

But is there any mathematical approach or any other way, with help of which we can determine the correct size that we should ask for once we get in-accurate results for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You will get an accurate result as long as aggregation `size` (bucket count) is not lower than the field cardinality. If cardinality is very high you may try to use a very high `shard_size` or bump `search.max_buckets` in the ES settings (and `size` of the agg) though it will affect the performance.